# dudas sobre verificación de contraseña en android studio kotlin

Tags: kotlin

quería consultar si alguien conoce el código de como funciona la validación de contraseña en kotlin ya que investigue en todos lados o no encuentro lo que busco o no se explica lo que busco

de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola bienvenido, que vallidación?, agrega más información a tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos,